# Sequelize Create or FindOrCreate never creates new records, only updates previous ones

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

When I use sequelize create it always updates the data in the table instead of creating a new one (id is auto increment)

When I ran the same command from mysql workbench it creates the new data correctly. Maybe i'm missing something in my setup...
**Sequelize version: sequelize:^5.22.3**
**Mysql Version: 5.5.62**

**model:**

```
const Merchants = sequelize.define('merchant', {
    merchant_id: { type: Sequelize.STRING(12), allowNull: false },
    shop_id: { type: Sequelize.STRING(75), allowNull: false },
    status: { type: Sequelize.TINYINT(4), allowNull: false },
    credits: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER(11), allowNull: false },
});
```

**create:**

```
Merchants.create({
    merchant_id: getNewMerchantID(),
    shop_id: shop_id,
    status: status,
    credits: credits
  }).then(merchants => {
    console.log(` created merchant: ${shop_id}`);
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log(` error creating merchant: ${error}`);
  })
```

**Console log**

```
Executing (default): SHOW INDEX FROM `merchants`
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `merchants` (`id`,`merchant_id`,`shop_id`,`status`,`credits`) VALUES (DEFAULT,?,?,?,?);
[merchantController] created merchant: SHOP_ID1
```

Btw I have the same problem with findOneOrCreate, it nevers inserts a new record, always updates the last record that was on the db

**findOrCreate**

```
try {
  //check if exists
  const [merchant, created] = await Merchants.findOrCreate({
    where: { shop_id: shop_id },//find this
    defaults: {//or create this
      merchant_id: getNewMerchantID(),
      //shop_id: shop_id, // does not need to repeat, its in the where clause
      status: status,
      credits: credits
    }
  });
  console.log(`[Merchants] created merchant: ${shop_id} [${created}]`);
  return created;
} catch (error) {
  console.log(`[Merchants] error creating Merchants: ${error}`);
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem
I was calling the code to create a new record of this model inside the promise from sequelize.sync, that apparently was always dropping the table and inserting new data what made it looks like it was overwriting

```
sequelize.sync({ force: true }).then(syncRes => {
     createMerchant("SHOP_ID1", 1, 999, "TOKEN");
   }).catch(error => {
     console.log(`sequelize synch error: ${error}`);
   });
```